# Parsing "quod Deus optime vertat"

Tags: idiom, contemporary-latin, academic-latin

I want to understand a diploma text:

> DIPLOMA
>
> QVOD DEVS OPTIME VERTAT
>   EX LEGIBVS
>
> VNIVERSITATIS JYVÄSKYLÄENSIS
>
> ATQVE EX DECRETO
>   FACVLTATIS (…)

If I consider *Diploma* as a title and *Quod Deus optime vertat* a subtitle (not grammatically tied to following text), I can parse the sentence starting *ex legibus universitatis Jyväskyläensis atque ex decreto facultatis…*: "by the rules of the University of Jyväskylä and by the decision of the faculty…".
The rest of the diploma makes sense as a sentence.

The real question is, **what does *quod Deus optime vertat* mean?**
The reason for giving additional context is that it might somehow be part of the sentence that the rest of the diploma forms.
I assume it is a separate "slogan", but there is no punctuation whatsoever and the layout does not give clear syntactical clues.
(If the second line is grammatically entirely separate from the third one, I will recommend to the university that a blank line be added in between for clarity.)

My best guess is that the second line means simply "May God bring success", and a separate sentence starts at the beginning of the third line.
I would like to be sure.

---

Here is the full text for a female graduating as a Master of Psychology (with the added empty row if my suspicion is correct).
Feel free to skip; this is just additional background information for the curious.

> DIPLOMA
>
> QVOD DEVS OPTIME VERTAT
>
> EX LEGIBVS
>
> VNIVERSITATIS JYVÄSKYLÄENSIS
>
> ATQVE EX DECRETO
>   AMPLISSIMAE RERVM CIVILIVM IN EA VNIVERSITATE FACVLTATIS
>   ABSOLVTO OMNI SPECIMINE LEGITIMO
>
> ARTIS PSYCHOLOGICAE MAGISTRA
>
> CREATVR OMNIBVSQVE HVIVS DIGNITATIS IVRIBVS PRIVILEGIISQVE ORNATVR
>   IN VRBE JYVÄSKYLÄ
>   IDIBVS AVGVSTIS ANNO MMXVI
>   FEMINA PRAECLARISSIMA
>
> <insert name of student>
>
> ARTIS PSYCHOLOGICAE CANDIDATA
>   QVOD FACTVM
>   NOMINE MEO SVBSCRIPTO ET SIGILLO VNIVERSITATIS ADFIXO
>   EGO CONFIRMO
>   LEGITIME CONSTITVTVS PROMOTOR
>
> <insert name of conferrer of degrees>

Quick English translation (as it seems to me) of the whole thing:

> Diploma
>
> May God bring success
>
> By the rules
>
> of the University of Jyväskylä
>
> and by the decision
>   of the great faculty of social sciences
>   after the completion of all due exams
>
> the exceptional lady
>   Bachelor of Psychology
>
> <insert name of student>
>
> is promoted to
>
> Master of Psychology
>
> and is equipped with all rights, privileges and insignia of this status
>   in the city of Jyväskylä
>   on August 13, 2016
>
> which I confirm by my signature and the seal of the university
>   as the legitimately appointed conferrer of degrees
>
> <insert name of conferrer of degrees>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Google search reveals several instances of *Quod Deus Optime Vertat* or simply *QDOV* in titles of things, but most of them seem similarly ambiguous.

However, a [letter](https://books.google.com/books?id=aK0MAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA270&lpg=RA1-PA270&dq=%22quod%20deus%20optime%20vertat%22&source=bl&ots=Td5uyqTVY4&sig=Y1rtFzGzBicbrlLgJ9s5Psw_OaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib7PXIwLnNAhULMj4KHS_bCQsQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22quod%20deus%20optime%20vertat%22&f=false) written on September 21 of 1520 in Frankfurt by Karl Gillert to Conrad Mutianus (as quoted in *Historical Sources of the Province of Saxony and Adjacent Areas*, volume 18, which seems to contain nothing but the correspondence between the two of them, which leads me to wonder to just how many volumes the series extends) contains the following paragraph (forgive me; I'm in a rush and can't take the time to figure out exactly who it's from or what the circumstances are, but when I return later I'll edit this answer to include that information).

> Huc princeps noster pientissimus vere pater Romani imperii, nedum patriæ et suorum incolumis cum suis pervenit heri, mi eruditissime præceptor Mutiane, cras Deo adjutore hinc navali profectione soluturus Agrippinam. **Quod Deus optime vertat**. Salutavit Hessorum principem id magnis precibus petentem exultante omni Hessia et applaudente.

The context, along with the other citations in titles, leads me to believe that your impulse is correct in believing that it's a separate saying or slogan: "May God turn it [= whatever matter is under discussion] to the best." If this is so, then yes, there definitely ought to be a line separating it from *ex legibus*, etc.

Comment: Thanks! It would make some sense to combine the first two rows to *diploma, quod Deus optime vertat*, but it's probably not intended. (How do I even express a wish in a relative clause in English? "Diploma, may God turn which to good"?) Searching for an alternative *quod Deus bene vertat* may or may not produce deeper enlightenment, but I guess a detached "may God bring success" is a decent translation.

Comment: I think "May God bring success" is just right. I suspect you're right that a combination of the first two lines isn't what was intended; otherwise, the material I quoted would read ***quam** Deus optime vertat*, no?

Comment: (And, alas, there's no way to express a wish in a relative clause in English. You'd have to say "Diploma; may God turn it to good.")

Comment: I believe *diploma* is one of those Greek neuters in the third declension, not a first declension feminine. (Good to know that about English relative clauses. I sometimes end up wanting unusual constructions.)

Comment: Right. I was figuring *quam* would go not with *diploma* on the degree but with *profectio* in the 1520 letter.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the letter it makes sense both grammatically and semantically that *quod* refers to the whole preceding sentence.

Comment: Joel Derfner, the second line of "For He's a Jolly Good Fellow," seems to me a an English optative following a relative pronoun: "Which nobody can deny."

Comment: Hmm. I'm having trouble reading it that way. To me it seems an indicative claim about the obviousness of the preceding statement: "For he's a jolly good fellow, which [assertion] nobody can deny [since it's so clearly true that everybody sees it]."