# What does Q.B.V.D. stand for on the title page of a dissertation?

Tags: new-latin, abbreviations

I have seen Q.B.V.D. as the first line of titles pages of academic dissertations, like this one:

[image]

https://books.google.nl/books?id=YmpZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=Q.B.V.D&source=bl&ots=28TRv2QHOi&sig=vN4j7q4dHlyMtc_MCW2i-5SU038&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Q.B.V.D&f=false

Does anyone have any idea what this stands for? I could fabricate guesses, but they would be completely arbitrary: none would be convincing at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's also – more commonly, I believe – given as Q. D. B. V. = *quod Deus bene vertat*, 'May God cause this to turn out well'/'May God grant this success.'

This use of *verto* is under definition 18 in the *Oxford Latin Dictionary*:

> **18** (esp. w. advs.) To turn the course of (affairs) to a specificed (favourable, etc.) outcome.

Two example of dissertations that are headed by Q. D. B. V.:

- [Example 1](https://archive.org/details/dissertatiogeogr00reic)
- [Example 2](https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/Lieber_Collection/pdf/Q.D.B.V_MiliteDesertore.pdf)

Comment: Your answer got me Googling which led me to this earlier post about Q.D.O.V so I leave it here for those interested: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/parsing-quod-deus-optime-vertat